# Is it possible to control focus distance of Sony Alpha 6* cameras using GPhoto2/libgphoto2?

Tags: manual-focus, tethering, sony-alpha, bracketing, programming

I'm trying to find or create a solution for automated focus bracketing for my Sony Alpha 6000 camera.

So far I have found only this PlayMemories Open Source application:
https://github.com/obs1dium/FocusBracket

It works but I lacks some features and the documentation for the SDK that it uses is absent (Sony doesn't publish it). There is an unofficial documentation though:
https://github.com/ma1co/OpenMemories-Framework

So I decided to try GPhoto2 and leave unofficial Java SDK as a last resort option.

I know that GPhoto2 allows to control focus distance in manual focus mode on some cameras and I wonder if someone ever did this with any of the Sony A6* cameras?

Comment: Are you sure about SDK? https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Comment: @RomeoNinov, this is another SDK, not for in-camera apps. It also was archived and replaced by another one. The SDK for creating in-camera apps is not provided by Sony AFAIK.

Comment: As you ask for desktop app this is the SDK which can help you with tethering! GPhoto2  is not in camera app.

Comment: About in camera app: have you consider this app https://www.playmemoriescameraapps.com/portal/usbdetail.php?eid=IS9104-NPIA09014_00-000001